# NHibernate Validator throwing and catching sqillions of MappingExceptions (property not found)

Tags: nhibernate-validator

After upgrading from NHibernate 2 to 3.1, NHibernate Validator is throwing and catching tons of MappingExceptions with the message "*property not found: myProp on entity MyEntity*".

The stack trace is:

> at NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.GetProperty(String
>   propertyName, IEnumerable`1 iter) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Mapping\PersistentClass.cs:line
>   921    at NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.GetProperty(String
>   propertyName) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Mapping\PersistentClass.cs:line
>   934    at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ClassValidator.FindPropertyByName(PersistentClass
>   associatedClass, String propertyName)

The NHibernate Validator source code for the method FindPropertyByName doesn't look too hot - there's just a large chunk of commented out code.

Is this just because NHibernate Validator is not ready for NHibernate 3, or is there a workaround?

Comment: Same Problem here! Upgraded nHibernate from 2.x to 3.1.0 incl. the corresponding nHibernate.Validator dll!
The error appears on all property which are NOT mapped in the hbm.xml! But these properties are just helper-properties...